# OSX Gatekeeper stopping my application

Tags: macos, cocoa, osx-gatekeeper, anthill

My application was working good before I added one library and a sub-project(both created by me). All are code signed with same value.

If I create a local DMG (using build-script) then it is getting installed on my system, also in other system. But the build taken from Anthill pro fails to pass the OSX Gatekeeper and shows "Un-Identified developer" issue.

What could be the issue that makes the same DMG to behave differently?

Comment: What is the error message (look in Console.app)?

Comment: It sounds like the certificate used for signing, by Anthill pro, isn't the same as that used by your local system.

Comment: @Droppy:Nothing is there in console logs

Comment: Try running `spctl -a` on the path in Terminal. The `-v` and `--raw` options might give more helpful output. `codesign -vv` might also reveal something. Is it possible the app is being signed with a version 1 signature instead of the now required version 2?

Answer (score 0):

I recently dealt with an issue with using a build server to sign an application. It signed fine, but then when we distributed it through our website, our users were asked to "Move to Trash" by OSX. My scenario was a little different, as I was using Jenkins, but perhaps the problem is the same.

I solved the issue by elevating our jenkins user up to an admin, and then running codesign with sudo.

I think this has something to do with signing as a developer vs. signing for distribution. If you download a signed package and your application was signed without distribution privileges, the extended attribute "com.apple.quarantine" gets places on the app package (check it by opening terminal and typing 'xattr [path-to-package]')